# Gtest: how to return different string value based on an increasing number every time in the expect_call?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

```
const std::wstring tesName[3] = { L"Final", L"Partial", L"Best"};
```

My gtest will call a function `GetName()` hundreds of times.
So I hope that the mocked function of `GetName()` can return like this:

```
int i = 0;
EXPECT_CALL(*my_mock, GetName()).Times(AtLeast(1)).WillRepeatedly(Return(tesName[(i++)%3]));
```

It can always returns the name comes from the array `tesName` from `Final` to `Partial` to `Best` then start from `Final` again. But the above code deson't work. How could I do that ?

No matter i is a local variable or a member variable of my gtest class, above code doesn't work.

In gmock document:

```
using testing::ReturnPointee;
...
 int x = 0;
MockFoo foo;
EXPECT_CALL(foo, GetValue())
  .WillRepeatedly(ReturnPointee(&x));  // Note the & here.
x = 42;
EXPECT_EQ(42, foo.GetValue());  // This will succeed now.
```

But I don't know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: Shouldn't `i` be a member of your test class for such case?

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforehand the number of times `n` the method should be called, you can do something like this:

```
{
  InSequence s;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    EXPECT_CALL(*my_mock, GetName())
        .WillOnce(Return(tesName[i % 3]))
        .RetiresOnSaturation();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I don't know the accurate value of n, can I set it to be a very large number, large number to cover the possible value of it ? Will that affect the gtest ?

Comment: That won't work, it will expect it to run exactly `n` times with the return value of each time specified. I don't know how to do it with arbitrary `n` -- you can look deeper into `gtest` docs, or rethink your test.